# Slice image src string with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, atom-feed

I am trying to pull the image src from an XML-based Atom Feed using PHP. I want to do this by slicing the string in the feed so that only the URL is grabbed.

So far I have been able to use the `substr()` command to slice a specific string length. The issue is the length of the image URLs will often vary in the feed, so I need to slice based on a specific character.

I tried using explode to specify a character to slice at:

```
foreach ($array['entry'] as $post) {
            if ($current > $max) break;
            $posts[] = [
            'post_img' => explode("\"", $post['content'], 2),
```

...but that didn't work. Here’s the XML code I am trying to pull from:

```
<content type="html">&lt;img alt="" class="attachment image image" src="http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg"
```

And here is the method in full. The `url`, `post_content` and `post_title` fields are all assigning correctly:

```
    $feed = getRssFile();
    if ($feed == false) return;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    $posts = [];
    if (count($array['entry'])) {
        $max = 3;
        $current = 1;
        foreach ($array['entry'] as $post) {
            if ($current > $max) break;
            $posts[] = [
            'post_img' => explode("src=", $post['content'], //isn't working
            'post_title' => $post['title'],
                'post_content' => substr(sanitizeContent($post['content']), 0, 200),
                'url' => $post['link']['@attributes']['href']
            ];
            $current++;
        }
    }
    return $posts;

}
```

explode() doesn't assign anything to the src field of the image when I check in the element inspector. It just says `img src(unknown)` Are there any alternatives to getting the result I need?

EDIT: here is what is returned from doing

```
           $exp = explode("src=", $thing);
            var_dump($exp[1]);
            var_dump($exp);
```

Result:

```
string(226) ""http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/c881c9ec924cfd1ee7f0650f2b6de9b36d4e31a9/store/limit/452/300/25f7a5696d2bd1d5e4d1137924ff04e3e2c8333fa8c71e005462a4e710d9/Walker_Recording.jpg" /><iframe style="border: none" " array(3) { [0]=> string(43) " string(226) ""http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/c881c9ec924cfd1ee7f0650f2b6de9b36d4e31a9/store/limit/452/300/25f7a5696d2bd1d5e4d1137924ff04e3e2c8333fa8c71e005462a4e710d9/Walker_Recording.jpg" /><iframe style="border: none" " [2]=> string(3454) ""//html5-player.libsyn.com/embed/episode/id/9576506/height/90/theme/custom/thumbnail/yes/direction/forward/render-playlist/no/custom-color/000000/" height="90" width="50%" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" oallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen=""><span id="selection-marker-1" class="redactor-selection-marker"></span></iframe> <p><em><br></em></p> <p><em>If you’re interested in more conversations like this on The New CCO, subscribe on&nbsp;<span class="redactor-unlink"></span><span class="redactor-unlink"></span><a href="https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/upskilling-a-workforce-reggie-walker-pwc/id1212422149?i=1000436862014" target="_blank">iTunes</a>,&nbsp;<span class="redactor-unlink"></span><a href="https://play.google.com/music/m/Dd6jidfd7eq4pzgwx7p3w6gigxm?t=Upskilling_a_Workforce_-_Reggie_Walker_PwC-The_New_CCO" target="_blank">Google Play</a>, or&nbsp;<span class="redactor-unlink"></span><span class="redactor-unlink"></span><a href="https://open.spotify.com/show/5oLW0nzEPyNo7mfcSFfIcu?si=gDn3b288RoiG8k9Xz9xH6g" target="_blank">Spotify</a>.</em></p> <p class="text-center">* * *</p> <p>Enterprises face severe disruption, whether via technology, business model, new competition, etc. In order to keep up, organizations must answer fundamental questions about the nature of their business, starting with their people. “What kind of culture do we need to compete in our industry? What does it look like, feel like, sound like? What are the base skills our people possess? Where do they come from?”&nbsp;</p> <p>These are some of the questions Reggie Walker, Chief Commercial Officer at PwC, has wrestled with while leading the enterprise's communications function over the past three years. He’s led a critical organization-wide effort around digital upskilling to better align PwC’s people with its business strategy. He’s also unified the Communications, Sales and Marketing functions, streamlining an operation that was once disparate entities.&nbsp;</p> <p>On this episode of The New CCO, we’ll learn more about each of these initiatives from Reggie and how they ladder up to a new kind of CCO role that’s swiftly changing in order to adapt to new disruptive factors.&nbsp;</p> <p>Here’s Reggie’s take on where he sees the future of work going over the next five years:</p> <p>“The opportunities are almost endless. We have to be responsible. And by that I mean there’s a lot of things we can do with technology. We have to make sure we’re not overextending the reach of certain technologies and cannibalizing jobs and opportunities. But, man, where will it not take us? That’s the fun part.”</p> <p><em>Do you have a story to tell? Share it with us. Please reach out to Justin Pallenik at <a href="mailto:jpallenik@page.org" target="_blank">jpallenik@page.org</a> with your CCO story.</em></p>" } string(3252) ""http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg" /><p>
```

And I want to just return each image source separately, such as

```
"http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/c881c9ec924cfd1ee7f0650f2b6de9b36d4e31a9/store/limit/452/300/25f7a5696d2bd1d5e4d1137924ff04e3e2c8333fa8c71e005462a4e710d9/Walker_Recording.jpg", "http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg"
```

Basically want to cut all of the other content out such as the text between the styling tags and other formatting.

EDIT 2 XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>tag:page.org,2005:/blog</id>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://page.org"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://page.org/blog.atom"/>
  <title>Blog | Arthur W. Page Society</title>
  <updated>2019-04-29T16:00:00Z</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>tag:page.org,2005:BlogPost/29039</id>
    <published>2019-04-29T16:00:00Z</published>
    <updated>2019-04-30T15:52:28Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://page.org/blog/the-new-cco-podcast-upskilling-a-workforce-reggie-walker-pwc"/>
    <title>The New CCO Podcast: Upskilling a Workforce - Reggie Walker, PwC</title>
    <content type="html">&lt;img alt="" class="attachment image image" src="http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/c881c9ec924cfd1ee7f0650f2b6de9b36d4e31a9/store/limit/452/300/25f7a5696d2bd1d5e4d1137924ff04e3e2c8333fa8c71e005462a4e710d9/Walker_Recording.jpg" /&gt;&amp;lt;iframe style=&amp;quot;border: none&amp;quot; src=&amp;quot;//html5-player.libsyn.com/embed/episode/id/9576506/height/90/theme/custom/thumbnail/yes/direction/forward/render-playlist/no/custom-color/000000/&amp;quot; height=&amp;quot;90&amp;quot; width=&amp;quot;50%&amp;quot; scrolling=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot; allowfullscreen=&amp;quot;&amp;quot; webkitallowfullscreen=&amp;quot;&amp;quot; mozallowfullscreen=&amp;quot;&amp;quot; oallowfullscreen=&amp;quot;&amp;quot; msallowfullscreen=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span id=&amp;quot;selection-marker-1&amp;quot; class=&amp;quot;redactor-selection-marker&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/iframe&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;em&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;em&amp;gt;If you’re interested in more conversations like this on The New CCO, subscribe on&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;redactor-unlink&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;redactor-unlink&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/upskilling-a-workforce-reggie-walker-pwc/id1212422149?i=1000436862014&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;iTunes&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;redactor-unlink&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;https://play.google.com/music/m/Dd6jidfd7eq4pzgwx7p3w6gigxm?t=Upskilling_a_Workforce_-_Reggie_Walker_PwC-The_New_CCO&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Google Play&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;, or&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;redactor-unlink&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span class=&amp;quot;redactor-unlink&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;https://open.spotify.com/show/5oLW0nzEPyNo7mfcSFfIcu?si=gDn3b288RoiG8k9Xz9xH6g&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Spotify&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;.&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p class=&amp;quot;text-center&amp;quot;&amp;gt;* * *&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Enterprises face severe disruption, whether via technology, business model, new competition, etc. In order to keep up, organizations must answer fundamental questions about the nature of their business, starting with their people. “What kind of culture do we need to compete in our industry? What does it look like, feel like, sound like? What are the base skills our people possess? Where do they come from?”&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;These are some of the questions Reggie Walker, Chief Commercial Officer at PwC, has wrestled with while leading the enterprise&amp;#39;s communications function over the past three years. He’s led a critical organization-wide effort around digital upskilling to better align PwC’s people with its business strategy. He’s also unified the Communications, Sales and Marketing functions, streamlining an operation that was once disparate entities.&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;On this episode of The New CCO, we’ll learn more about each of these initiatives from Reggie and how they ladder up to a new kind of CCO role that’s swiftly changing in order to adapt to new disruptive factors.&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Here’s Reggie’s take on where he sees the future of work going over the next five years:&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;“The opportunities are almost endless. We have to be responsible. And by that I mean there’s a lot of things we can do with technology. We have to make sure we’re not overextending the reach of certain technologies and cannibalizing jobs and opportunities. But, man, where will it not take us? That’s the fun part.”&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;em&amp;gt;Do you have a story to tell? Share it with us. Please reach out to Justin Pallenik at &amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;mailto:jpallenik@page.org&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;jpallenik@page.org&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt; with your CCO story.&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</content>
    <author>
```

Comment: Yes there is, but if you want a better answer then you need to give us an example string.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just added example string. Thanks!

Comment: How are you processing this XML? What is `$array`? What is `$post`? Provide a [mcve] please!

Comment: An XML sample would help also; just enough to reproduce the question. This is the "C" in MCVE that I linked above.

Comment: Ok just added XML sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using explode correctly for what you're trying to do. [Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
<?php
$thing = "<content type=\"html\">&lt;img alt=\"\" class=\"attachment image image\" src=\"http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg\"";
var_dump($thing);
$exp = explode("src=", $thing);
var_dump($exp);
?>

[root@test ~]# ./test.php
string(246) "<content type="html">&lt;img alt="" class="attachment image image" src="http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg""
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(67) "<content type="html">&lt;img alt="" class="attachment image image" "
  [1]=>
  string(175) ""http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg""
}
```

The extra quotes are a by-product of shoving it into a string for example's purposes, but this will get you the URL if it's consistently the last element of the string. If it's not you can take $exp`[1]` and explode it again using space (" ") as the needle and $exp`[1`] as the haystack. The resulting array will have the URL as its first element.

---

Update to OP Comment/Code:

*Please* read the documentation for explode.

> $thing is assigned to a specific string

Explode only works on strings. If I'm interpreting you correctly, the xml value that I put into my example string...

```
<content type="html">&lt;img alt="" class="attachment image image" src="http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg"
```

is the value of `$post['content']`. If that's the case, then this is the string you want to explode. The part you're missing:

**Explode returns an array**

To get a single piece of an exploded string, you need to reference the correct index of the resulting array. Look at my initial example again to see exactly what explode returns:

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(67) "<content type="html">&lt;img alt="" class="attachment image image" "
  [1]=>
  string(175) ""http://awpagesociety.com/attachments/20aa91b841d6a49dd945a97af37509add2680573/store/limit/452/300/e6941ac426f6cbca5774cad6f2e8b6447c96d92d32957be6709dac201de7/Brady-Bush.jpg""
}
```

It's an array filled with strings. By assigning explode's return to that key `'post_img'`, you're making the value an entire array, not a single string. Creating a multi-dimensional array within $posts and then trying to reference values as if they were single elements, this is never going to work.

If this still doesn't make things clear, provide a full example of the XML being returned by `simplexml_load_file()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I am having trouble still with this. In your example, $thing is assigned to a specific string, but in the above code sample I updated on my question, $thing would have to pull dynamically from the XML feed since there would be 3 total img srcs that would update frequently. I also don't know where to declare the var...i'm guessing it would have to be outside the for loop? Sorry for all of the questions I am still new with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I updated my code in my question. What you suggested did help by shortening the content, however I still am trying to isolate just the img src URLs. I want to explode it further, but I am unsure of what the best way to explode the string so that there is just a list of srcs left (ex: string[0]->"http://...", string[1]->"http://..." etc.

Comment: @ChrisMcGlade So based on what you've already shown and have now seen, you should be able to do this. You know how to isolate the string that contains src information and you can explode that string to get just the URL you want. Process as many XML entries as you like and decide what to do with each URL once you've isolated it. If you want them in an Array, put them in an Array. My advice is as a beginner to any language, not to worry too much about the 'best' way to do anything, that only comes with time and is always a little subjective. Just 'make it work' and then see what can be improved.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for your help :) If anyone else runs into this problem, here is my working code ```           $thing = $post['content'];
           $exp = explode("src=", $thing);
             $exp2 = explode("\"", $exp[1]);
            $list = [];
            $list = $exp2[1]; ```